# UV Map - Changes direction midway

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I hope that will be my last question about UVs in blender.

I now have an object unwrapped. The Quads are sometimes not exactly squares. On one site they get smaller so its a trapeze. Therefore when the UV is a normal square the uv tiles should get smaller to the smaller site of the square but in my case they are randomly changing direction like it can be seen in the image.

[image]

[image]

Here is my blender file so that you can look up my UV:

[BlenderFile](https://www.file-upload.net/download-12665683/SE_File2.blend.html)

Comment: That is a consequence of straightening UV maps. They are straightened so ratio of UV island doesn't correspond to ratio of the face. Try unwrapping Project From View and you will see the difference. You can go with less geometry by using Project from View for both top and bottom of the mesh (other way for the middle) or by adding seams in the corners of the mesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem related to uv coordinate interpolation. It is inevitable when working with very low mesh density. To avoid
this kind of problem increase mesh resolution by adding few extra loops.

As you can see the distortion runs along triangles - this is the way uv is interpolated in quad polygons.

Comment: Okay thank you. That kind of fixed it. Not perfectly but I dont want to add 10 loops to each side jsut to get rid of it 100% .

Sadly this is adding far more polys (with subdivide) for such a simple object.

Comment: Yeah thats true. For any model the less distorted the triangles would be the better it is for uv interpolation. Very narrow triangles tend to turn ugly in uv maps unless you keep the overall shape of the unwrapped face as in project from view